# When EditText Request Focus , Keep its location constant

Tags: android, android-edittext, scrollview

I have a scrollview in which there are some EditTexts. When one of the EditText request focus, it moves the view. I want view not to be moved.

I have written code as below, but at this time i am not able to write to EditText.

```
myEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

    if(hasFocus){


    myScrollView.pageScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_UP);

    myEditText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

    myEditText.setSelection(kisisel_bilgi_TCKN.getText().length());

    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)    getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.showSoftInput(myEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
     }
});
```

How can i solve this?

Comment: What do you mean 'not able to write'? Like does the EditText lose the focus after that code is executed?

Comment: @erdemgc :: remove this line  myScrollView.pageScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_UP); from your code

Comment: @KMI if i remove that line, i lose the scroll,

Comment: @erdemgc : have you tried that ? actually moves the view to top position

Comment: @erdemgc: please try that and if you find any issue let me know

Comment: @KMI yes i have tried. my problem was the scrolling of edit text and i was losing the position of top menu. by adding myScrollView.pageScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_UP) i have reached my goal. but this time the problem is not being able to write to edittext

Comment: Try by adding this line inside if(hasfocus)conditon  myEditText.setEnabled (true);

Comment: @KMI setEnabled also not a solution, since it has got focus but not writable somehow

Comment: does it popping out the keyboard the when the edittext has focus?

Comment: @KMI yes keyboard appears, but touching the keys does not affect edittext

Comment: post your code and corresponding xml file